# Pie slice not visible on loading

Tags: highcharts

I have developed a pie chart with 4 slices.
Everything works excellent apart from one issue.

For a particular user the 4th slice is always invisible with the space of the slice being blank.
When we hover on its legendItem the slice appears and stays from there on.
This happens only in IE7 and IE9 document mode 7. 
I guess it has something to do with VML but I am not sure.

The same chart works fine everywhere else.

Is this a known issue or any pointers as to what the issue can possibly be?
I am unable to reproduce this anywhere else.
Also, how do we call the legendhover event programatically after chart creation. I would like to put in this hack fix for the time being at-least.

Comment: please recreate your example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I cannot share my code.I know the information given by me is not much to go on. Have you heard of such a problem before? Would it be possible to tell me how do we call the legendhover event programatically after chart creation?

Comment: You can iterate on each series legend Item and catch mouseover action by .on() function. http://jsfiddle.net/RUhzg/

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for some way to force invoke hover event call of the legenditem, so that I can call it after the chart is loaded and the pie slice will show up to the user on loading.

Comment: In my example hover event is fired after chart initialization, so what is wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. I can see that the mouseover event is being assingned. But I dont see it explicitly being invoked in the code.

Comment: I added mousover, so you need to add mouseout, and it will be the same as hover.

Comment: My doubt is regarding explicitly invoking the event. Not assigning a function to the event.

Comment: On debugging I find that for each data point the total is total 99.99249554538748.. Could this be the reason for the chart not appearing properly?

Comment: So in which circumstances, event should be invoked? I mean, when action like hover fucntion, should be called?

Comment: Just wanted to invoke the function on chart load.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using the below code in the chart load function.

```
if (chart.renderer.isVML != undefined && chart.renderer.isVML== true) {
                this.setState();
            }
```

This ensured that when the chart is loaded all the pie slices are showing up.
Do you think its advisable? Have you heard of anyone else facing this issue?